# Rails Highchart not looping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I'm using Lazy Highcharts to generate a graph from my database. I have the loop situated in my controller and it loops the columns correctly, but the categories it only lists the last inputed site, not sure why this is.

**Controller**

```
def index
  @nutritiontrials = Nutritiontrial.all

  @plantstand = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
    @nutritiontrials.each do |trial|
      f.xAxis(:categories => [trial.site])
      f.series(:type => 'column', :name => 'Plant Stand Treated', :data => [trial.nil_plant_stand_est], :color => '#00463f')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It looks like each iteration resets the xAxis and series rather than appends to it.

Comment: Thanks David, I have this working now. I created the loop outside of the LazyHighCharts code and called an array. Updated code below for anyone else who might have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @nutritiontrials = Nutritiontrial.all
    sites = []
    plant_stand = []

    @nutritiontrials.each do |trial|
      sites << trial.site
      plant_stand << trial.nil_plant_stand_est
    end  

    @plantstand = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
      f.xAxis(:categories => sites)
      f.series(:type => 'column', :name => 'Plant Stand Treated', :data => plant_stand, :color => '#00463f')
    end
```